# How to display a background for full body height

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

I am trying to display some random display images on the background of body load. For that i have a function. Now the issue is the images are getting displayed for the whole page until the web browser can scroll which is very lengthy I want it to be displayed only till body height and width. following is the code i am using:

```
var body = document.body;
var html = document.documentElement;
var bodyHeight = Math.floor(Math.min(body.scrollHeight));
var htmlHeight = Math.floor(Math.min(html.scrollHeight));

var height = Math.max(bodyHeight, htmlHeight);

for(i=0; i<height; i++){
var images = [],


---------------
-----------------
image array here
--------------------
-------------------------
index = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);

document.write(images[index]);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The body is the whole page. What you want is the screen height and width.
For that create a div inside the body and put the image as background of the div, using as units 100vh, 100vw;

https://devcode.la/tutoriales/unidades-vh-vw-css/

Answer (score 0):

Just do this

```
body{
background-image:url('');
background-position:100% 100%;
**background-size:cover;**
width:100%;
background-attachment:fixed;
 }
```

You ensure the background-size property is set to "cover".

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, the body is the whole page.  You want the 'viewport' width/height.  That's what the other answer covers.  Another approach just use CSS to set the background image of the html tag like so:

```
        <style>
        html {
            background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1478427433968-28045906c1dd?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&s=f1c8cb36c65c1e472e0ebf9ef6d4eac5');
            background-size: cover;
            background-position: center;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            height: 100%; min-height: 100%;
        }
        </style>
```